# What is the initializing procedure underneath the __init__ method of python built-in list

Tags: python, list, initialization, subclass

My question is will the **init** method of list class calling other method such as append or insert to achieve its functionality.

like:

```
class test(list):

def __init__(self,values):
    super().__init__()

def append(self, value):
    self.append(value + 1)
```

I want:

```
x = test([1,2,3])
x
[2,3,4]
```

but I got:

```
[1,2,3]
```

I know I can make it work by overload **init** itself.

```
def __init__(self,values):
    super().__init__([x+1 for x in values])
```

Can I just overload some basic value insert method like **setitem**, so all the insert operation like append, insert will call it, and therefore have that addition effect.

thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen another example overriding form `collections.MutableSequence`that would let you get this functionality. I'm not sure if this is more convenient than your initial idea, but it will increment any numbers during `__init__`, `append`, `insert`, and `extend`

```
class IncList(collections.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, int_list):
        self._list = []
        for el in int_list:
            self.append(el)

    def __len__(self): return len(self._list)
    def __getitem__(self, item): return self._list[item]
    def __delitem__(self, item): del self._list[item]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self._list[index] = value + 1

    def insert(self, index, value):
        self._list.insert(index, value + 1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._list)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%r)" % (self.__class__, self._list)


> l = IncList([1, 2, 3])
> print(l)
[2, 3, 4]
> l.append(4)
> print(l)
[2, 3, 4, 5]
> l[0] = 0
> print(l)
[1, 3, 4, 5]
> l.extend([5, 6])
> print(l)
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> l.insert(1, 1)
> print(l)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3488283/2821252) for more information.

Comment: That's the way I was looking for! What's the difference between MutableSequence and built in list? Are they essentially same?

Comment: I'm no expert, but that's my understanding. MutableSequence is an abstract base class that inherits from Sequence and implements all of the same methods as list.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It really helps.

Comment: @Jians one caveat is that this implementation will increment moved items when `l.reverse()` is called. Sorting doesn't seem to be a problem though

Comment: got it, sort is not really problem

Answer (score 4):

`list.__init__` does not call any overrideable method. It makes a [direct, un-overrideable call](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/listobject.c#L2315) to the C function that implements the `extend` method:

```
if (arg != NULL) {
    PyObject *rv = listextend(self, arg);
    if (rv == NULL)
        return -1;
    Py_DECREF(rv);
}
```

This is the case for most methods of most Python types implemented in C.

Comment: So, I have to overload all the element inserting method to achieve the addition functionality? Including append, insert and extend? That's sad news. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Jians: I find it beats the usual situation, where you have no idea what overrides will affect or interfere with what other methods. People don't do enough to think about or document the API they provide to subclasses.

Comment: For those people whose daily work is not programming, find the exact document is really a tough work. And that's why stackoverflow is the best place to learn from experienced expert.