# TypeError: 'Food' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
self.food_list = [['apple', 100, 'Fruit', 384.0], ['orange', 100, 'Fruit', 384.0]]
```

I want to sum the element from the index 3. 
Expected output is `Total calorie of all food is 768.0Kcal`

```
def totalCalorie(self):
    for i in range(0, len(self.food_list)):
        j = self.food_list[i][3]
        j += j
    print("Total calorie of all food is {}Kcal".format(j))
```

But the following error came out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PythonTim/Assignment/nutritionDriver.py", line 60, in <module> 
    main()
  File "D:/PythonTim/Assignment/nutritionDriver.py", line 43, in main
    patient.totalCalorie()
  File "D:\PythonTim\Assignment\nutritionApp.py", line 132, in totalCalorie
    j = self.food_list[i][3]
TypeError: 'Food' object does not support indexing
```

The thing I want to do is when the user wants to total up all the calories that in the list, the system will display the total calories from the list.

Is there another way to do it? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, name, quantity, category, calorie):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.category = category
        self.calorie = calorie

class FoodList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.food_list = []

    def totalCalorie(self):
        j=0
        for i in self.food_list:
            j += i[3]
        print("Total calorie of all food is {}Kcal".format(j))

    def addFood(self, newfruit):
        self.food_list.append(newfruit)

name = input("Name? ")
quantity = input("Quantity? ")
category = input("Category? ")
calorie = input("Calorie? ")
f = Food(name, quantity, category, calorie)
patient = FoodList()
patient.addFood(f)

name1 = input("Name? ")
quantity1 = input("Quantity? ")
category1 = input("Category? ")
calorie1 = input("Calorie? ")
f1 = Food(name1, quantity1, category1, calorie1)
patient.addFood(f1)

patient.totalCalorie()
```

Comment: Are you sure self.food_list has the value you expect it to have? When I copy your code it works. (there is a flaw with your logic of j += j, but that's not causing the error)

Comment: please submit the entire class

Comment: what happens when you try printing type(self.food_list)?

Comment: @MohammadAthar i put self.food_list = [] in FoodList constructor so I tried type(FoodList.food_list) but came out with this : AttributeError: type object 'FoodList' has no attribute 'food_list'

Comment: @UriGoren I can't even if I shorten it, it not allowed me to post because of too much code

Comment: self.food_list is a instance-based object (that is, it is created when you create an instance of the class), it's different from FoodList.food_list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem when running your code (but I had to imagine the class since you are not giving it).

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self):
            self.food_list = None
    def totalCalorie(self):
            for i in range(0, len(self.food_list)):
                    j = self.food_list[i][3]
                    j += j
            print("Total calorie of all food is {}Kcal".format(j))

f = Food()
f.food_list = [['apple', 100, 'Fruit', 384.0], ['orange', 100, 'Fruit', 384.0]]
f.totalCalorie()
```

Output : "Total calorie of all food is 768.0Kcal"

PS: I'm using Python2.7

**EDIT 1 :**

As pointed out by Lukas Ansteeg in the comments of your post "there's a flaw with your logic of j += j"

You should do this instead :

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self):
        self.food_list = None

    def totalCalorie(self):        
        total = 0        
        for i in range(0, len(self.food_list)):
            j = self.food_list[i][3]
            total += j
        print("Total calorie of all food is {}Kcal".format(total))
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Now that I have your entire code, there are two problems that I can highlight :

1. You are trying to use indexing on a Food object but your Food object does not support indexing the way you have constructed it, please read [this (from doc)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487434/overriding-append-method-after-inheriting-from-a-python-list/3488283#3488283) if you really want to use an object that support indexing.
   Anyway, you can easily solve this problem by accessing the attribute "calorie" of your Food object instances instead. So `j += i[3]` becomes `j += i.calorie` but it won't work because (see point 2)
2. Input returns a string, therefore i.calorie is a string and you must do `j += float(i.calorie)` or you will get a TypeError (Python, unlike Javascript, does not accept string and integer concatenation)

Finally your code becomes this :

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, name, quantity, category, calorie):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.category = category
        self.calorie = calorie


class FoodList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.food_list = []

    def totalCalorie(self):
        j = 0
        for i in self.food_list:
            j += float(i.calorie)
        print("Total calorie of all food is {}Kcal".format(j))

    def addFood(self, newfruit):
        self.food_list.append(newfruit)


name = input("Name? ")
quantity = input("Quantity? ")
category = input("Category? ")
calorie = input("Calorie? ")
f = Food(name, quantity, category, calorie)
patient = FoodList()
patient.addFood(f)

name1 = input("Name? ")
quantity1 = input("Quantity? ")
category1 = input("Category? ")
calorie1 = input("Calorie? ")
f1 = Food(name1, quantity1, category1, calorie1)
patient.addFood(f1)

patient.totalCalorie()
```

Output :

```
Name? apple
Quantity? 100
Category? Fruit
Calorie? 384.0
Name? Coq_au_vin
Quantity? 1
Category? Delicious_meal
Calorie? 142000.0
Total calorie of all food is 142384.0Kcal
```

I hope I have been helpful with this but, like I said in the comment, you REALLY should read some good material about OOP like the "Head First" series or if you prefer something more interactive there are great courses and tutorials on Udemy.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to do "for i in self.food_list"?

Comment: @Leonhard Triendl -> absolutely but I wanted to keep his code mostly untouched for the sake of clarity ;)

Comment: in my code the class constructor has self.food_list = []

Comment: @OysterD3 can you edit your original post to include the full code ? It will be much easier to understand your problem like this.

Comment: @SirRobin I can't, it say that too much code in the post even if I shorten it, is there another way to send you?

Comment: @OysterD3 sadly there isn't a PM function on StackOverflow. As I read of the comments between your original post I've understand that you have problems understanding the concept of classes and instances. Therefore I strongly suggest you to read a good tutorial / book about the concepts of OOP ;)

Comment: I have updated my code, similar to my old code. Please check, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the elements of food_list.
As an improvement to Sir Robin's answer:

```
class Food:
    food_list = []

    def totalCalorie(self):
        j=0
        for i in self.food_list:
            j += i[3]
        print("Total calorie of all food is {}Kcal".format(j))

    def addFood(self,newfruit):
        self.food_list.append(newfruit)


f = Food()
f.addFood(['banana', 100, 'Fruit', 100.0])
f.addFood(['orange', 100, 'Fruit', 384.0])
f.totalCalorie()
```

I edited the `j +=` part too, so that it works also with more than 2 elements.

Comment: What if the element in the list is input by the user? When user called the addFood method, it will append into the list. I can't make it food_list = None in the constructor. It will cause me another error.

Comment: I edited my answer, so that you can add as much food as you like

Comment: Your answer is helping me a lot, I found that the error was in my other class. I have already updated, please check. Thanks in advance!